# Winform treeview sorted property is slow

Tags: winforms, treeview

I have a winforms `TreeView` control with the [`Sorted` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.sorted.aspx) set to true. I also override the default sorter by assigning and instance of `IComparer` to the `TreeViewNodeSorter` property.

Unfortunately adding a few thousand nodes using the `AddRange` function takes perhaps 10 seconds. If I set `Sorted` to false the `AddRange` function is < 1/2 second. (please no discussions about the validity of adding so many nodes)

Aha I hear you say.. there is a problem in my `IComparer` object. Not according to the profiler. Barely any time is spent in the sorting object and yet the `AddRange` function is right at the top of the list of slow functions.

The problem is easy to replicate in a test project. Simply create a list of `TreeNode`s and add it to the an existing expanded tree node using the `AddRange` function. This will use the default sort on the tree text - again it is disproportionately slow.

To demonstrate how disproportionately slow it is if I disable the `Sorted` property in the test probject and use the `List<T>.Sort` function (with a delegate that compares the Text of the nodes) on my list of nodes before adding them to the tree there is virtually no delay.

This leads to the workaround of sorting the nodes manually before using `AddRange`. That's OK but it means a lot of work to find the correct insertion point when adding nodes to an existing set of child nodes - rather less convenient than simply setting `Sorted` to true.

Is there anyway to speed up the behaviour?

EDIT - it seems the only way is to sort before adding.. it's a bit of a hassle but I came up with the following extension method:

```
public static void AddSortedRange(this TreeNodeCollection existingNodes, IList<TreeNode>    nodes, TreeView treeView, IComparer sorter)
    {
        TreeNode[] array = new TreeNode[nodes.Count + existingNodes.Count];

        existingNodes.CopyTo(array, 0);

        nodes.CopyTo(array, existingNodes.Count);

        Array.Sort(array, sorter);

        treeView.BeginUpdate();

        existingNodes.Clear();

        existingNodes.AddRange(array);

        treeView.EndUpdate();
    }
```

It is quicker to copy the existing nodes to an array, append the new nodes, sort the array and then replace that trying to manipulate nodes inline in the tree view - the slowest operation in the above code is the `existingNodes.Clear()` call

Comment: How about sorting _before_ adding?

Comment: Can't you just set Sorted to true only once all nodes have been added?

Comment: @UweKeim - as stated in the question there is a fair amount of extra work to insert nodes in an existing set of nodes - especially merging a range into an existing collection

Comment: @ken2k - that just shifts the delay to the Sorted property.. and its the same with leaving Sorted as false and calling the Sort() function after the Add unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

The performance problems you have are related to the fact that you are adding items to a sorted **TreeView**. What happens behind the scenes when you add to a sorted list is that for **each** item that you are adding, it tries to find it's place, which means that it needs to go through the **whole list** for **each item**, now imagine how many iteration that makes for each new item :)

What you can do is this:

```
TreeView tv = new TreeView(); // Just so I have a TreeView variable
TreeNode[] nodes = ... // Well, your list of nodes that you want to add
tv.SuspendLayout();
tv.Sorted = false;
tv.Nodes.Clear();
tv.Nodes.AddRange( nodes );
tv.Sorted = true;
tv.ResumeLayout();
```

For performance reasons we are using the **SuspendLayout/ResumeLayout** methods to disable the painting process used by the **TreeView** when manipulating it's items, which we would cause by removing the items and then adding them as well, since it would need to repaint to add the new item that you are adding (for each of the items).

Right before we are doing any changes to the ***Nodes Collection*** we have to call ***Sorted = false;*** to disable the sorting (this is just temporary - the user will not see any changes because of **SuspendLayout**).
Then just add the items to the collection (since the **TreeView** is not sorted for the time being it should be really quick).
Then we enable the sorting again by calling ***Sorted = true***; setting the Sorted Property to true will cause for the collection to do a sort.
This way, the sort will be performed only once (and therefore the **TreeView** will just go once through the items).

One more thing, if you have a custom sorter defined for the ListView (tv.ListViewItemSorter), set it to null before adding the items as well, just temporary of course, re-enable it again before the ResumeLayout call.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a locking situation using the Sort() method.

It worked fine for weeks, then once, it stucks, stucking my application with 25% CPU in the task manager.

```
var allTags = _TagEngine.GetTags(1, force);

try
{
    TagTree.BeginUpdate();
    TagTree.Nodes.Clear();
    foreach (var rec in allTags)
    {
       ... adding nodes in the tree
    }

    TagTree.Sort(); // <= stuck here !
}
finally
{
    TagTree.EndUpdate();
}
```

So I watch inside the Sort() method using a decompiler, and I noticed it handles already the BeginUpdate/EndUpdate feature internally.

Then I moved the TagTree.Sort() outside the BeginUpdate/EndUpdate, and it works fine since.

```
var allTags = _TagEngine.GetTags(1, force);

try
{
    TagTree.BeginUpdate();
    TagTree.Nodes.Clear();
    foreach (var rec in allTags)
    {
       ... adding nodes in the tree
    }
}
finally
{
    TagTree.EndUpdate();
}

TagTree.Sort();
```

I hardly understood what happened here. Why it worked in the past, and suddenly stoped. Frankly, I did not had time enough to dig further and anyway, the most important is here : it works again.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple extension to the TreeView control. It is very fast. It moves internal storage to a Dictionary which makes a huge difference. In my real world example I have 100000 records that I need to load. It took 37 minutes before, but now it takes 2.2 seconds!!

You can find example and code on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/679563/Fast-TreeView